# Loop not going to next element

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set every cell in Column C to Blank if its cells match the value in column B

This is my code

```
For Each b In Columns("B").Cells
    For Each c In Columns("C").Cells
        If b.Value = c.Value Then
        c.Value = Null
    Next c
Next b
```

b and c are both declared as ranges.

The error I get is "Next without for".

Any idea why?

Comment: You're missing the `End If`.

Comment: Also you are going to loop 1.04^2 million times.  You may want to limit the loops to just the range of data.

Comment: Please show the full code as it's very difficult to tell if your error is in the snippet or you've gone wrong before or after it.

Answer (score 0):

this is a better approach i think....

```
dim rNg as range
dim rCell as range

set rNg = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("your range") 'im assuming B:B in my code

for each rCell in rNg.Cells
    if rCell.Value <> vbNullString And rCell.Offest(0,1).Value <> vbNullString then
        if rCell.Value = rCell.Offset(0,1).Value Then
            rCell.Offset(0,1).Value = vbNullString
        End If
    End If
next rCell
```